# Is it legal to access private non-static first data member of a standard layout class?

Tags: c++, access-modifiers, standard-layout

For a standard layout class, [it is legal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) to convert a pointer to an object of the class to a pointer to the first non-static data member of the class. Now assume that the first non-static data member happens to be a private member. Is this a legal way to modify a private data member outside class' member function?

If not, could you indicate what part of standard prevents it?

Note: The purpose here is to understand the standard better, not to do this in actual code.

Comment: This question would benefit from a code example of what you are asking about.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432576/can-a-private-variable-be-accessed-through-its-address

Comment: AFAIK this is legal, as long as your class really is standard layout.  That means all data members have to have the same access modifier.

Comment: Think of `public`, `private`, and `protected` (Key term: Access Specifiers) as tools to help prevent simple mistakes. They are easily circumvented, for good or evil, if you want to.

Comment: What is *your* definition of a "standard layout class"?  At my work, I have yet to see any "standard layout class".  Some classes may have private data members while others have protected data members.  The layouts may differ too (some people may want to have private members first, others want the interface first).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Well, this is well known that C++ define what is a standard layout class. And a link to `std::is_standard_layout` is also provide in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"assume that the first non-static data member happens to be a private member"*

That's fine, if *all* non-`static` data members are `private`. From the C++20 final working draft:

[`[basic.compound]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.compound#4)

4. Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:

   1. they are the same object, or
   2. one is a union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object ([`[class.union]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.union)), or
   3. one is a **standard-layout class** object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, any base class subobject of that object ([`[class.mem]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mem)), or
   4. there exists an object `c` such that `a` and `c` are pointer-interconvertible, and `c` and `b` are pointer-interconvertible.

---

11.2 Properties of classes [`[class.prop]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.prop#3)

3. A class `S` is a **standard-layout class** if it:

   1. — has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
   2. — has no virtual functions (11.7.2) and no virtual base classes (11.7.1),
   3. — **has the same access control (11.9) for all non-static data members,**
   4. — has no non-standard-layout base classes,
   5. — has at most one base class subobject of any given type,
   6. — has all non-static data members and bit-fields in the class and its base classes first declared in the same
      class, and
   7. — has no element of the set M(S) of types as a base class, where for any type X, M(X) is defined as
      follows.101 [Note: M(X) is the set of the types of all non-base-class subobjects that may be at a zero
      offset in X. — end note]

      1. — If X is a non-union class type with no (possibly inherited (11.7)) non-static data members, the set
         M(X) is empty.
      2. — If X is a non-union class type with a non-static data member of type X0 that is either of zero size
         or is the first non-static data member of X (where said member may be an anonymous union), the
         set M(X) consists of X0 and the elements of M(X0).
      3. — If X is a union type, the set M(X) is the union of all M(Ui) and the set containing all Ui, where each Ui is the type of the i th non-static data member of X.
      4. — If X is an array type with element type Xe, the set M(X) consists of Xe and the elements of M(Xe).
      5. — If X is a non-class, non-array type, the set M(X) is empty

Comment: How strange. [In C++23](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1847r4.pdf) the memory layout always matches the declaration order, regardless of modifiers. This bullet still being there looks like a defect to me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat C++23 has a lot of examples, like this: `struct T { int i; private: int j; };` which is said to be _"trivial but not standard-layout"_. Could that be what you were thinking of?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat see https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/728